# Looking at paypal API - What is cURL?

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I've been looking at several examples of utilizing paypal's API to develop a simple script to be able to use it to checkout, and in each one I keep running across cURL, and I really don't understand it at all. Is it just different PHP functions from a library, or something all together different? More importantly, can I copy and paste cURL commands into my document and it will work, or do I need to download something to get it work on my local server and shared hosting server where my live site will go? Lastly, where can I go to learn this? I've done some searching but haven't found any solid material on it. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A basic understanding of cURL example from PHP Manual**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

**cURL with PayPal API . [Found it on the internet]**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$clientId = "myId";
$secret = "mySecret";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json->access_token);
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple form to the checkout. To use via cURL you need to enable cURL and use it in your PHP code.

The following is the simple way.

```
<form action="https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sandy_1314264698_biz@gmail.com ">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="sand bag">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1234">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://abc.com/xyz.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://google.com">

    <!-- Display the payment button. --> 


<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="btn_subscribe_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">  
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
```

Comment: I'm comfortable using this form method, but I feel it lacks security? Either way, once I get to IPN I'll need to use cURL to verify the response from paypal.

Comment: This is the form supplied by paypal itself. You are just sending the information to paypal as there will be no transaction info supplied, it will be feasible to use. To verify the response, paypal sends the information back to your return URL where you can catch the response. There will not be a need to use cURL at all.